How do 'zip' recursively but exclude files of a certain name wherever it appear in any subfolder?
For example I have files:
./otherfile1
./otherfile2
./excludethisfile
./folder1/otherfile
./folder1/excludethisfile
./folder2/otherfile
./folder2/excludethisfile

I want to zip all files recursively but always exclude the file called 'excludethisfile'
====
To answer whether the post "How do I zip up a folder but exclude the .git subfolder" answers the question:
NO that post is referring to a very simple case of excluding a single subfolder from the zip.
My case is about excluding files of a certain name that might appear in any subfolder, in multiple places, and I want to exclude every one of those files, wherever they appear.
Also this is NOT the case of excluding files of a certain extension ( e.g. .o ), but rather by name ( e.g. filename ).

Does this answer your question? How do I zip up a folder but exclude the .git subfolder

It should work to use the --exclude option, first a 'dry run' showing what to zip,
zip -sf -r file.zip .  --exclude \*/excludethisfile

then, when things look good, do it with
zip -r file.zip .  --exclude \*/excludethisfile

In this case the wild card * will represent the directory path to the files to be excluded.

Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

You are welcome, I'm glad that I could help you find a solution :-)
